# Filter by lowest and highest years by group using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I feel like the answer here is obvious, but I can't nail it down. I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(SIC = c(3L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 17L, 1L, 
10L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 
18L, 5L, 19L, 17L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 
13L, 3L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 17L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 
2L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 17L, 
1L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 12L, 11L, 
7L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 17L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 
4L, 13L, 3L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 17L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 
14L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 
17L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 12L, 
11L, 7L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 17L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 
9L, 4L, 13L), year = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018), value = c(NA, 0.081, 0.218, 0.212, NA, 0.092, 0.142, 
0.001, 0.045, 0.143, 0.361, 0.175, 0.295, 0.003, 0.146, 0.01, 
0.163, NA, 0.225, NA, 0.108, 0.274, 0.219, NA, 0.097, 0.148, 
-0.049, 0.098, 0.26, 0.251, 0.153, 0.262, 0.119, 0.096, 0, 0.149, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.064, 0.27, 0.16, NA, 0.103, 0.148, -0.029, 0.084, 
0.219, 0.314, 0.142, 0.255, 0.026, 0.031, -0.003, 0.164, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.257394804, 0.124025397, NA, 0.071727544, 0.13439, 
-0.017419321, 0.091993981, 0.171021874, 0.308369685, 0.208573024, 
0.310316421, 0.06216349, 0.074913633, -0.034273066, 0.181129287, 
0.07876301, 0.121, NA, -0.063226494, 0.233968039, 0.179367136, 
NA, 0.105362761, 0.15319907, -0.033967241, -0.035027867, 0.144316565, 
0.304955404, 0.069662044, 0.304262651, 0.075256422, 0.051273353, 
-0.067541918, 0.157814304, 0.050231459, 0.06308377, NA, -8.4, 
21, 17.9, NA, 7.3, 12.6, -1.2, 4.1, 10.3, 30.2, 8.7, 28.1, 4.7, 
1.3, -7.7, 12.5, 15.9, 19.4, 16.9, 4, 18.2, 13.5, NA, 10.9, 12.8, 
-0.7, 4.2, 7.5, 26.8, 5, 30.3, 0.9, 2.5, -2.4, 13.5, 12.8, 17, 
NA, NA, 17.2, 17.7, NA, 0.6, 11.6, -2.9, 3, 18.7, 31, 6.2, 30.1, 
-1.1, 5.7, -0.5, 13.6, 6.1, -7)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -152L))
```

I would like to filter it by the lowest AND highest year. So that all values have both a lowest and highest year column. I'm going to `split`/`spread` and compare these two columns. My approach has been to `group_by` on SIC, then `filter` on `!is.na(value)`, but this returns way to few values. There is one group of SIC that only has one value, thus its lowest and highest years should be same. This is what I've tried so far and have filtered too many values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(SIC) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(min(year), max(year)))

# A tibble: 35 x 3
# Groups:   SIC [18]
     SIC  year value
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    12  2011 0.081
 2    11  2011 0.218
 3     7  2011 0.212
 4     5  2011 0.092
 5    19  2011 0.142
 6    17  2011 0.001
 7     1  2011 0.045
 8    10  2011 0.143
 9     8  2011 0.361
10    16  2011 0.175
# ... with 25 more rows
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:

A simple version of the data would be to filter like this:

```
tibble(
  SIC = c(1,1,1,2,2, 2), 
  year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2013), 
  value = c(3, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA)
) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    SIC  year value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2011     3
2     1  2012     4
3     2  2012     4
```

All rows that appear once should count as both the minimum and maximum value. Is there a way to make a duplicate row for those rows that appear only once after the filter is applied?

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: @arg0naut, see my edits.

Comment: @elliot see below, I think `slice` should do it as it automatically repeats the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `slice`:

```
tibble(
  SIC = c(1,1,1,2,2, 2), 
  year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2013), 
  value = c(3, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA)
) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(SIC) %>%
  slice(which.min(year), which.max(year))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   SIC [2]
    SIC  year value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2011     3
2     1  2012     4
3     2  2012     4
4     2  2012     4
```

Try the above approach on your initial data frame, and you should also see a difference with `filter`.

For `SIC` number 3, for instance, `slice` gives:

```
# A tibble: 36 x 3
# Groups:   SIC [3]
    SIC  year   value
  <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1  2011   0.045
2     1  2018   3    
3     2  2011   0.003
4     2  2018  -1.1  
5     3  2017  16.9  
6     3  2017  16.9
```

i.e. it repeats the year, while `filter` just keeps whatever corresponds to the argument:

```
# A tibble: 35 x 3
# Groups:   SIC [18]
     SIC  year    value
   <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1  2011   0.045 
 2     1  2018   3     
 3     2  2011   0.003 
 4     2  2018  -1.1   
 5     3  2017  16.9   
 6     4  2014   0.0788
```

I'm using `dplyr 0.8`.

Comment: thanks this works. Note I did have to update my `dplyr` to use two variables in `slice`.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for letting me know, I thought it's been there before 0.8 - have updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

my understanding is that you want to have two rows for SIC whose max year and min year is the same. I think you can split the two and bind it so that it will still have 2 rows.

```
library(dplyr)

min_year <- df %>% 
  group_by(SIC) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(min(year)))

max_year <-  df %>% 
  group_by(SIC) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(max(year)))

total <- min_year %>% rbind(max_year)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(SIC) %>% group_by(SIC) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
       filter(year %in% c(year[which.min(value)],year[which.max(value)])) %>% 
       bind_rows(filter(.,n()==1),.)


# A tibble: 36 x 3
# Groups:   SIC [18]
SIC  year    value
<int> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     3  2017  16.9   
2     1  2015  -0.0350
3     1  2017   4.2   
4     2  2016   4.7   
5     2  2018  -1.1   
6     3  2017  16.9   
7     4  2015   0.0502
8     4  2016  15.9   
9     5  2014   0.0717
10     5  2017  10.9   
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are hoping to achieve. Hope it helps :)

```
#Create two tibbles (MAX & MIN)
max.vals<-df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  slice(which.max(value))

min.vals<-df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  slice(which.min(value))

#Create new DF, with MAX & MIN for each (unique) year:
clean.df<-data.frame(SIC=max.vals$SIC,
             year = max.vals$year,
             max.value = max.vals$value,
             min.value = min.vals$value,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> head(clean.df)
  SIC year  max.value   min.value
1   8 2011  0.3610000  0.00100000
2  11 2012  0.2740000 -0.04900000
3   8 2013  0.3140000 -0.02900000
4  14 2014  0.3103164 -0.03427307
5   8 2015  0.3049554 -0.06754192
6   8 2016 30.2000000 -8.40000000
```

**EDIT**
I am a terrible person, I just saw you wanted it by SIC. No worries, hope this is what you need:

```
SIC.low<-df %>%
  group_by(SIC) %>%
  slice(which.min(value))

SIC.high<-df %>%
  group_by(SIC) %>%
  slice(which.max(value))

clean.df2<-data.frame(SIC=SIC.high$SIC,
                     year.high = SIC.high$year,
                     max.value = SIC.high$value,
                     year.low= SIC.low$year,
                     min.value = SIC.low$value,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


> head(clean.df2)
  SIC year.high max.value year.low   min.value
1   1      2017      4.20     2015 -0.03502787
2   2      2016      4.70     2018 -1.10000000
3   3      2017     16.90     2017 16.90000000
4   4      2016     15.90     2015  0.05023146
5   5      2017     10.90     2014  0.07172754
6   6      2011      0.01     2016 -7.70000000
```